# Limiting results in SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

From a table do I want to select the first 4 rows after the first one. I had this in MySQL working as the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `yp_playlist` LIMIT 1, 4;
```

I have done some research to see the SQL Server version of this query and came out on the following but this keeps resulting me into an error which keeps me clueless for now.

```
SELECT id, entry 
FROM (
    SELECT id, entry, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNum
    FROM playlist
) AS MyDerivedTable
WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

This is the error:

> *There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3, Token line offset = 36, Token in error = OVER ]*

Comment: which version of SQL Server?  Check your db compatibility setting

Comment: Run this (replace DBNAME with the name of your database) and tell us the result: `SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'DBNAME'`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SQL Server Compact 4.0 you can use;

```
SELECT * FROM [Orders] ORDER BY [Order Date] OFFSET 1 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM ( SELECT id, entry 
       FROM playlist 
       ORDER BY id )
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to `set rowcount`

e.g

```
set rowcount 4
```

then order your data so you get the ones you want at the top